# Как узнать находиться ли значение "X", в столбце "A1" в Excel через openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Ситуация: Нужно добавить нового пользователя с уникальным id.

Что должно происходить: Если данного id нет в столбце "A1", то мы его добавляем. Если же данный id уже внесен в нашу БД, то мы его предупреждаем, о том что он уже был добавлен.

Как добавлять и предупреждать я знаю, но не знаю как проверить, есть ли данный id в БД.
Если нужна какая-то дополнительная информация по вопросу, спрашивайте.

```
 @dp.message_handler(commands=['reg'])
 async def RegId(message: types.Message):
   wb.active = 4
   sheet = wb.active
   player_id = message.from_user.id
   #Вот в этом промежутке должна быть проверка, есть ли id в BD
   print(player_id, '<<< BotLog')
   colvo = sheet['A1'].value
   sheet['A1'].value = colvo + 1
   wb.save(filename='Game.xlsx')
   Pcolvo = sheet['A1'].value
   await message.answer(f"Ваш порядковый номер: {Pcolvo}")
   a = Pcolvo
   sheet['A' + str(a)].value = player_id
   wb.save(filename='Game.xlsx')
   await message.answer(f"Регистрация успешно пройдена. Ваш ID 
   {message.from_user.id}")
   print('ID_Player >>>', player_id)
   print(sheet['A2'].value, sheet['A3'].value)
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU, добавил свой код и обозначил место проверки, где нужно узнать, есть ли player_id, в БД